# toggleClass not removing first class

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I have the following html:

```
<div class="profileRowHeader">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" id="folderIcon"></i>
</div>
```

When `.profileRowHeader` is clicked I want to remove class `glyphicon-folder-close` and add class `glyphicon-folder-open` to `#folderIcon`

This is what I'm trying:

```
$('.profileRowHeader').click(function() {
    $(this).find("#folderIcon").toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-open','glyphicon-folder-close');
});
```

But all it does is simply add the `glyphicon-folder-open` class and not remove the `glyphicon-folder-close` class as below:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close glyphicon-folder-open" id="folderIcon"></i>
```

Is this expected behaviour? I really need to remove it if possible

Comment: do like this `--> 'glyphicon-folder-open glyphicon-folder-close'` put both in same quotes without `,` separated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like

```
$('.profileRowHeader').click(function() {
    $(this).find("#folderIcon").toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-open glyphicon-folder-close');
 });
```

For the two classes you dont need any seperator ratherthan **space**.See this [**link**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 6):

You list the classes to toggle in *one*, space-delimited string:

```
$(this).find("#folderIcon").toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-open glyphicon-folder-close');
// Change is here --------------------------------------------^
```

The second (optional) argument to [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) isn't another class to toggle, it's a flag: If it's truthy, the `toggleClass` acts like `addClass`. If it's falsey, `toggleClass` acts like `removeClass`. If it's *missing*, `toggleClass` *toggles* the classes (removes them if present, adds them if absent, on a class-by-class basis).

Answer (score 3):

In your case you should use a single string argument with classes separated by space:

```
$('#folderIcon', this).toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-open glyphicon-folder-close');
```

Answer (score 2):

`toggleClass` takes a single string parameter with each class to toggle being separated by a space. Try this:

```
$('.profileRowHeader').click(function() {
    $(this).find("#folderIcon").toggleClass('glyphicon-folder-open glyphicon-folder-close');
});
```